# Docker : What packages should I apt-mark hold to keep a specific docker version?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want that all Linux Ubuntu servers I work with use the same docker version. I also want that if I run an `apt-get upgrade` command the docker related packages stay on this version and don't auto upgrade.

The first part was easy, it was explained in the official docker doc. For the second part I used `apt-mark hold docker-ce` after installing the specific docker version.

But after an `apt-get` upgrade a few weeks later I noticed that the containerd.io version shown by the `docker version` command was different than before.

I am not sure if this has any consequences. So my question is what packages, if any, should I `apt-mark hold` besides `docker-ce`?
`docker-ce-cli`? `containerd.io`? `runc`?
Or should I only hold `docker-ce` and let the other packages do their upgrades?